# Expression in data attribute for angular chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, chart.js

Hi I have tried using an expression inside the data attribute like this

```
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <canvas data="getTheData(item.value)"></canvas>
     </div>
```

and in the controller

```
var getData = {
    first: function(){ return angularFactory.getData() };
    second: function(){ return angularFactory.getData() };
}


$scope.getTheData = function(value){
  getData[value]().then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
};
```

my plan is to get only the needed data from factories based on what items the user load.

the problem is this is resulting in [$rootScope:infdig] with a log that never stops even though I just have one item in the "item" list.

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: You are passing `undefined` to `data` attribute.

Comment: No, I'm getting the data I want to get in the logs only not only once as I want it.

I actually pass the complete item in the getTheData(item)

Comment: @Stellan give a try by my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have something like this, I'm not sure this will work or not

Call an `getTheData` on rendering of `DOM`, you should pass `item` inside that method instead of `item.value`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="getTheData(item)">
    <canvas data="item.data"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.getTheData = function(item){
  getData[item.value]().then(function(data){
      item.data = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
};
```

So inside the success of `getData` function you need to set `item.data` value that will get passed to canvas `data` attribute.

Comment: Thanks I will try this, only one question though, will the chart be able to update on changes if the data is only loaded on init?

Comment: @Stellan yes..as you provide the reference of `item.data` to directive, it will update the chart as data comes in

Comment: Works great! thank you!! saved alot of time, haven't tried it with any $watch function yet but I suppose it will work! :)

Comment: @Stellan don't go for watcher..used this approach..that would be cleaner..could I know why you wanted to go for implementation with watcher?

Comment: I use firebase as backend for the charts and I want them to update when there is new data

Comment: I'm not completely sure how to set up the watcher though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87566/discussion-between-stellan-and-pankaj-parkar).

Comment: @Stellan I can't come on chat right now.I'm busy..sorry